# How to Disable Responsiveness in Bootstrap in col-lg-up (CSS)

Tags: html, css

I want to make my site responsive on phones and tablets but I want to make it static on computers. How can I create this?

I was thinking bout somehow disabling responsive in col-lg and up, but how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly , you can use col-xl-... prop, this is for displays that are >=  1200 .

Can you give me more information , what really want to do ?

You can make something like that  , this will make your container to fit on small screens with 50% and for bigger screens 1200 + will fit on 100% of row.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simple, i just needed to make a fixed width. Without coding in bootstrap.